# Xamarin: Using HttpClient POST in combination with a dynamic Class

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin, json.net, httpclient

I have some services that require rather complex objects. Every service uses almost the same base object but it needs to be extended for each service.

A simple example:
The Standard Object would be something like:

```
ContextObject {
    params {
       Device {
          Name: "MyMobileDevice",
          ID: 123455691919238
       }
    }
}
```

and for my service I need to add some properties under `params`,
something like:

```
ContextObject {
    params {
       Device {
          Name: "MyMobileDevice",
          ID: 123455691919238
       },
       requested_employee_id: 112929
    }
}
```

I tried to get this by using `JObject` and got it working so far but now I cant find a proper example on how to send this object to my server using `HttpClient`.

Edit:
Here is my full JObject which all Requests need:

```
        public static JObject DefaultContext (string ServiceMethod) {
        var Context = new JObject();
        Context["version"] = "1.1";
        Context["method"] = ServiceMethod;
        Context["params"] = JObject.FromObject( new {
            Context = JObject.FromObject( new {
                User = App.UserSettings.USERNAME,
                Password = App.UserSettings.PASSWORD,
                SerialNumber = "1234567890", // TODO: use generated id
                Locale = "de-DE",
                Timestamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH\\:mm\\:ss.fffzzz"),

                Device = JObject.FromObject( new {
                    DeviceType = "phone",
                    ProductType = "D6603", // TODO: Get from Device-Info
                    screen = JObject.FromObject( new {
                        Density = "xxhdpi", // TODO: Get from Device-Info
                        resolution = JObject.FromObject( new {
                            Height = "1920", // TODO: Get from Device-Info
                            Width = "1080" // TODO: Get from Device-Info
                        })
                    }),
                    version = JObject.FromObject( new {
                        AppVersion = "myAppVersion", // TODO: Get App-Information                           LayoutVersion = "1.0"
                    } )
                })
            })
        });

        return mobileContext;
    }
```

For my Requests I need to add parameters under the "params"-Node. Which works with:

```
mobileContext["params"]["mynewparameter"] = "FOO";
```

Now I wanted to send this JObject via System.Net.Http-Client to my server with something like this:

```
var client = new HttpClient ();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri (App.UserSettings.HOST + ":" + App.UserSettings.PORT + App.UserSettings.TYPE);
client.Timeout = 3000;      

var context = MyContext.DefaultContext (ServiceMethods.CUSTOMER_LIST_METHOD);   
context ["params"] ["myrequestparam"] = "FOO";
var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject (context);
var responseData = await client.Get???????
```

Is my general approach correct? How would you do it? Is there a sample on how to handle such dynamic stuff?
I couldn't find a example on how to use httpclient correctly with the Newtonsoft.JSON-Library how far am I from actually working code?

Comment: Hi JavaLui, welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your post to make it a little clearer: I removed some unnecessary greetings/thanks (while polite, on SO it's considered unneeded info that shouldn't be in a question), and I also fixed up some spelling/minor formatting issues. Your question seems pretty clear, but it might help people if you expand a little bit on what you've tried with `JObject` and what you're trying to do with `HttpClient`. Hope you get some answers!

Comment: Thank you for that. I'll add my JObject-Source later this day do help clear things out.